# Pass user id and password instead of git token with out curl to Git api

Tags: git, github

How can I pass user id and password instead of git token with out curl to Git api. This is my code :

```
def pullPayload
String listOfPullRq = "https://github.myorg.com/api/v3/repos/myorg/myrepo/pulls"
pullPayload = json.parse(listOfPullRq.toURL().newReader(requestProperties: ["Authorization": "token mytoken".toString(), "Accept": "application/json"]))
```

I can do it by passing git token but in my use case I need to pass the git user id and password instead of git token . How can I do that?

Comment: You can do half-basic authentication by passing the username.  You're not able to pass a password in to that form, at least from what I've read of their API docs.

Comment: Use OAuth or the personal access token. These can be scoped and revoked easily.

Comment: Yeah, i ended up with using oath token instead . Could not find a way to pass user id and password .